# Link a field in content types to the user profile

Tags: nodes, navigation

I want to link the output of a field (e.g. "Written by:Name" or "Photographed by:name") in the content type (e.g. Article) to the user profile.

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should make sure that the default author relationship isn't sufficient to satisfy your needs. Every content type has a creating user; this relationship can usually be used to create any necessary links between the content and the user in Views, Panels, or other modules.

However, sometimes you need to have multiple users associated with content. Your "photographed by:" example sounds like a good example of this use case. In that instance, I would use the [User Relationships module](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) to add a User Relationship field to the content type.